# Jquery Not loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, sticky

I am trying to make a sticky navigation behavior but the jQuery script seems not to be working or loading.

This is my html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="logo-menu">
    <div id="main-menuid">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu">Menu</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/source.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some more markups to make my page scroll down to test the sticky navigation.

This is the source.js:

```
(function() {
    // STICKY NAV
        console.log('hi')

    var $nav = $('#logo-menu'),
        navTop = $nav.offset().top,
        $navClone = $nav.clone(true)
            .hide()
            .addClass('sticky')
            .insertBefore($nav);

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > navTop) {
            $navClone.show();
        } else {
            $navClone.hide();
        }


    });
```

Even the `console.log('hi')` doesnt show up on firebug console. Any idea? or did i miss something? TIA!

Answer (score 2):

Your function is wrapped in parentheses. If you remove the function body, you're left with this:

```
(function() {});
```

I think either you wanted to produce a self-executing function, in which case you're missing the second set of parentheses to actually execute the function:

```
(function() {})();
```

Or you were trying to use the jQuery shorthand for `$(document).ready`, in which case you're missing the `$`:

```
$(function() {});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not executing the function.

Try adding `()` to the function like this: `(function(){})()`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a $ at the start.

Edit this part

```
(function() {
```

like this

```
$(function() {
```